# How to get texture data using textureID's in openGL

Tags: opengl, textures

I'm writing some code where all I have access to is a textureID to get access to the required texture. Is there any way that I can get access to the RGB values of this texture so I can perform some computations on it?

EDIT: I am looking for the inverse of `glTexSubImage2D`. I want to get the texture data rather than replace it.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You are probably looking for [`glGetTexImage`](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/GLAPI/glGetTexImage)

Before using `glGetTexImage`, don't forget to use [`glBindTexture`](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/GLAPI/glBindTexture) with your texture ID.

Comment: How do you get a piece of a texture (i.e. rectangle)?

Comment: I think you will have to render it to an FBO and then read from that with glReadPixels.

Answer (score 1):

In OpneGL a texture can be read by [`glGetTexImage`/`glGetnTexImage`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glGetTexImage.xhtml) respectively the DSA version of the function `glGetTextureImage`.

Another possibility is to attach the texture to a framebuffer and to read the pixel by [`glReadPixels`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glReadPixels.xhtml). OpenGL ES does not offer a `glGetTexImage`, so this is the way to OpenGL ES.
See [opengl es 2.0 android c++ glGetTexImage alternative](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53993820/opengl-es-2-0-android-c-glgetteximage-alternative/53993894#53993894)

---

If you transfer the texture image to a [Pixel Buffer Object](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Pixel_Buffer_Object), then you can even access the data via [Buffer object mapping](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Buffer_Object#Mapping). See also [OpenGL Pixel Buffer Object (PBO)](http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_pbo.html).
You've to bind a buffer with the proper size to the target `GL_PIXEL_PACK_BUFFER`:

```c
// create buffer
GLuint pbo;
glGenBuffers(1, &pbo);
glBindBuffer(GL_PIXEL_PACK_BUFFER, pbo);
glBufferData(GL_PIXEL_PACK_BUFFER, size_in_bytes, 0, GL_STATIC_READ);

// get texture image
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture_obj);
glGetTexImage(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, (void*)(0));

// map pixel buffer
void * data_ptr = glMapBuffer(GL_PIXEL_PACK_BUFFER, GL_READ_ONLY);

// access the data
// [...]

glUnmapBuffer(GL_PIXEL_PACK_BUFFER);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm writing this here just in case anyone needs this.

In 4.5+ OpenGL, one can access a textures' data by giving a texture ID by using the
[**glGetTextureImage()**](https://docs.gl/gl4/glGetTexImage) function.

For example in order to get a GL_RGB texture data,
we have 3 floats R,G,B each one of each is 4 bytes so:

```
float* data = new float[texture_height * texture_width * 3];
glGetTextureImage(textureID, 0, GL_RGB, GL_FLOAT, texture_height * texture_width * 3 * 4, data);
```