# glTextureStorage3D and glTextureSubImage3D are not working

Tags: kotlin, opengl, lwjgl

I would like to use multiple textures, but stucking.
I tried to bind multiple textures with using, `glTextureStorage3D` and `glTextureSubImage3D`.
I wrote following code by Kotlin.

```kotlin
    // generate textureId
    val tex = BufferUtils.createIntBuffer(1).run {
        glCreateTextures(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, this)
        this.get(0)
    }

    // using STBImage, retrieve image file's width, height and bytebuffer
    val textures = texturePaths.mapIndexed { idx, texture ->
        loadTexture(idx, tex, texture)
    }

    glTextureStorage3D(
            tex,
            1,
            GL_RGB,
            textures.maxBy { it.width }!!.width,
            textures.maxBy { it.height }!!.height,
            textures.size
    )

    textures.forEach { texture ->
        glTextureSubImage3D(tex,
                0,
                0,
                0,
                texture.index,
                texture.width,
                texture.height,
                1,
                GL_RGBA,
                GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,
                texture.img
        )
    }
    ...
}

private fun loadTexture(idx: Int, tex: Int, texture: String): Texture {

    val width = BufferUtils.createIntBuffer(1)
    val height = BufferUtils.createIntBuffer(1)
    val comp = BufferUtils.createIntBuffer(1)
    val img: ByteBuffer = STBImage.stbi_load(texture, width, height, comp, STBImage.STBI_default)
            ?: throw IllegalStateException("Failed to load $texture")

    logger.debug("$texture load OK")
    val texObj = Texture(idx, width.get(0), height.get(0), comp.get(0), img)

    STBImage.stbi_image_free(img)

    return texObj
}
```

After executed `glBindTexture` and call `glGetTexImage` by texureId, no image data returned.
I referred following SO post.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/5117806/2565527

How to bind textures correctly ?

Comment: "*I tried to bind multiple textures with using*" Neither of those functions require a texture to be bound.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found textures are legitimately loaded. But, a parameter `int internalformat` is incorrect. If we used `GL_RGB`, alpha value is not used. So I misunderstood it's not loaded correctly. I just changed `GL_RGB` to `GL_RGBA8` and the problem is resolved.

```kotlin
    glTextureStorage3D(
            tex,
            1,
            GL_RGBA8,
            textures.maxBy { it.width }!!.width,
            textures.maxBy { it.height }!!.height,
            textures.size
    )
```